# Which regex removes punctuation from quotation marks in text

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a database and throughout the text there are some quotes that are in quotation marks. I would like to remove all the dots "." that are enclosed in quotation marks in the text.

I have code that punctuates text in quotation marks but if there is more than one quote or more than one point, only the first one is removed.

```
# Simple phrase:
string <- '"é preciso olhar para o futuro. vou atuar" no front '

# Code that works for a simple 1-point sentence:
str_replace_all(string, '(\".*)\\.(.*\")','\\1\\2')

# Sentence with more than one point and more than one quote:
string <- '"é preciso olhar para o futuro. vou atuar" no front em que posso 
fazer alguma coisa "para .frente", disse jose.'

# it doesn't work as i would like
str_replace_all(string, '(\".*)\\.(.*\")','\\1\\2')
```

I would like all the points in quotation marks to be removed, but you can see from the example that the regex I developed is not for more general cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may simply use `str_replace_all` with a mere `"[^"]*"` pattern and use a callback function as the replacement argument to remove all dots with a `gsub` call:

```
str_replace_all(string, '"[^"]*"', function(x) gsub(".", "", x, fixed=TRUE))
```

So,

- `"[^"]*"` matches all substrings in `string` starting with `"`, then having 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- Once the match is found, it is passed to the callback as `x` where `gsub(".", "", x, fixed=TRUE)` replaces all `.` (`fixed=TRUE` makes it a literal dot, not a regex pattern) with an empty string.

Comment: Wow, `function (x)` in the `replacement` argument was the trick!

Answer (score 4):

```r
mystring <-'"é preciso olhar para o futuro. vou atuar" no front em que posso 
fazer alguma coisa "para .frente", disse jose.'
```

You can use the following `pattern` with `gsub`:

```
gsub('(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\\.', "", mystring, perl = T)
```

Same with `stringr`:

```r
str_replace_all(mystring, '(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\\.', '')
```

***Output:***

```
#> "é preciso olhar para o futuro vou atuar" no front em que posso 
#> fazer alguma coisa "para frente", disse jose.
```